# Use free space to make a new filesystem

Tags: rhel, filesystems, partition, fdisk

How would I go about using 50G of the free space from `vg_root` to make a new filesystem and then use that for `/home`

```
nifle@rhel8box3 ~
$ sudo lsblk
[sudo] password for nifle:
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                   8:0    0  300G  0 disk
├─sda1                8:1    0  512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                8:2    0  512M  0 part /boot
└─sda3                8:3    0  299G  0 part
  ├─vg_root-lv_root 253:0    0   60G  0 lvm  /
  └─vg_root-lv_swap 253:1    0   16G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb                   8:16   0   50G  0 disk
└─sdb1                8:17   0   50G  0 part
  └─vg_var-lv_var   253:2    0   50G  0 lvm  /var
sr0                  11:0    1 1024M  0 rom

nifle@rhel8box3 ~
$ sudo vgs
[sudo] password for nifle:
  VG      #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree
  vg_root   1   2   0 wz--n- <299.00g <223.00g
  vg_var    1   1   0 wz--n-  <50.00g       0

nifle@rhel8box3 ~
$ sudo lvs
  LV      VG      Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv_root vg_root -wi-ao----  60.00g
  lv_swap vg_root -wi-ao----  16.00g
  lv_var  vg_var  -wi-ao---- <50.00g
```

Comment: Do `mkdir /home` then use?

Comment: @JamesRisner It seems like they want to separate out `/home` onto a new partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest solution is alocate 50Gig to a new Logical Volume (LV) in vg_root.
Then you can set the desired File System an mount it:

```
lvcreate --size 50G --name new_lv vg_root
lvs
mkfs.ext2 /dev/vg_root/new_lv
mkdir -p /home
mount /dev/vg_root/new_lv /home
```

Comment: I understand where you are going with the instructions, but they wouldn't work as they stand. `sudo` will need to be used, and creating /home on a system that already has /home will not work, if one manages to mount the new filesystem it will overlay the existing home directory, which should first be transferred to the new filesystem. If someone followed your instructions as it stands it wouldn't really work. Please update, so that it makes sense. tks.

Comment: `new_vg`, when is that created

Comment: Thanks for point out the mistake. I corrected the name of the already existant VG.